# Implementing a simple text adventure game in java (working with interfaces)

Tags: java, oop, game-engine, composition

I was doing some reading on [ECS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system#Design_of_an_entity)/[Composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) and decided to modify a text adventure game that I'm currently working on to better understand the concept.

I decided to try it using a specific weapon in my game.

Now, in my game the logic is that every Weapon is considered an IGameObject. With all this in mind I came up with the following:

Weapon Interface:

```
public interface IWeapon {
    int getWeaponDamage();
}
```

Weapon class:

```
public class Weapon implements IWeapon {

    private int damage;

    public Weapon(int damage)
    {
        this.damage = damage;
    }

    @Override
    public int getWeaponDamage() {

        return this.damage;
    }
```

IGameObject interface:

```
public interface IGameObject {

    String getGameObjectID();
    String getGameObjectName();
    String getGameObjectDescription();
}
```

GameObject class:

```
public class GameObject implements IGameObject {

    private String ID;
    private String name;
    private String Desc;

    public GameObject(String ID, String name, String Desc)
    {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.name = name;
        this.Desc = Desc;
    }
```

The abstract class that uses all this:

```
public abstract class GameGun implements IGameObject, IWeapon {

    IGameObject gameObj;
    IWeapon weaponObj;

    //Left out getters to keep it simple and easy to read.
    public GameGun(IGameObject game, IWeapon weapon)
    {
        this.gameObj = game;
        this.weaponObj = weapon;
    }
    public void fire()
    {
        System.out.println("Shot Fired");
    }

    public void reload()
    {
        //implementation for reload method
    }
```

Putting it all together:

Main Method:

```
    GameObject sleep = new GameObject("SLP-1","Sleep Weapon","A Custom Made Gun");
    Weapon sleepDamage = new Weapon(10);

    GameGun sleepWeapon = new SleepWeapon(sleep,sleepDamage);
```

Questions:

1. I just wanted to know if my implementation was correct?
2. If not, how would I correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been correcting many stuff and get it working. You can play with it now :D
PLease take the gist in order to have all the working code.

**CONSOLE**

```
Revolver Gun:Gun reloaded
Revolver Gun:Gun shots => 10 damage(s)
Basic Sword:Sword cuts =>  5 damage(s)
Basic Sword:Sword cuts =>  5 damage(s)
Basic Sword:Sword cuts =>  5 damage(s)
Revolver Gun:Gun shots => 10 damage(s)
```

**CODE**

```
package com.rizze.test.labs.sof.gamegun;

import org.junit.Test;

public class GameGunTest {


    @Test
    public void betterCode2() {

        Game sleep = new Game("SLP-1","Sleep Weapon","A Custom Made Gun");
        Gun gun = new Gun();
        Sword sword = new Sword();

        gun.hit();
        sword.hit();
        sword.hit();
        sword.hit();
        gun.hit();
    }



    public class Gun implements IWeapon {

        private int damage;
        private String name;

        public Gun(int damage)
        {
            this.damage = damage;
            this.reload();
        }

        public Gun()
        {
            this.damage = 10;
            this.name= "Revolver Gun";
            this.reload();
        }

        @Override
        public int getDamages() {

            return this.damage;
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @return damages
         */
        @Override
        public int hit() {
            System.out.println( this.name + ":Gun shots => "+damage +" damage(s)");
            return this.damage;
        }

        @Override
        public void reload() {
            System.out.println(this.name+":Gun reloaded");          
        }

    }


    public class Sword implements IWeapon {

        private String name;
        private int damage;

        public Sword(String name){  
            this.damage = 5;
            this.name=name;

        }

        public Sword(){ 
            this.damage = 5;
            this.name="Basic Sword";

        }

        @Override
        public int getDamages() {

            return this.damage;
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @return damages
         */
        @Override
        public int hit() {
            System.out.println( name+ ":Sword cuts =>  "+damage +" damage(s)");
            return damage;
        }

        @Override
        public void reload() {
            System.out.println( name+ ":Sword - skipped reload" );          
        }

    }





    public class Game implements IGame {

        private String id;
        private String name;
        private String desc;

        public Game(String ID, String name, String Desc)
        {
            this.id = ID;
            this.name = name;
            this.desc = Desc;
        }

        @Override
        public String getId() {
            return this.id;
        }

        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return this.getName();
        }

        @Override
        public String getDesc() {
            return this.desc;
        }
    }



}
//IGAME

public interface IGame {

    String getId();
    String getName();
    String getDesc();
}


 //IWEAPON 

package com.rizze.test.labs.sof.gamegun;

    public interface IWeapon {
        int getDamages();
        int hit();
        void reload();
    }
```

**GIST**
here is the complete GIST  :https://gist.github.com/jeorfevre/92d093853bfd3fc5c666b915b309abf1

Comment: I didn't understood why you needed a gamegun object? So in the betterCode() example I'm not using it ! See the example ! enjoy :D

Comment: Many thanks for this! Glad to see I was on the right track. I had a GameGun abstract class because NOT every weapon is a gun. I might also want Sword. GameGun would handle the basic actions of a Gun. While weapon just returns and keeps the damage.

Comment: 90% of your code was working. I would not do a GameGun class since you will repeat the boilerplate code again and again to pass the returns of functions. Have you been thinking of scala for writting your game. Code is lean and clean. Worth the cost taking a look to it! Also consider voting if solution was good for you :).

Comment: Given that not every weapon is going to be a gun, would it be better to have an IGameGun and then create the gun directly instead of through an abstract class?

Comment: use IWeapon, and use it for all you weapon do not create a lot of interface since you will loose a lot of the Interface meaning/interest in java! Keep it simple. Updated response with sword & gun (also gist)